# Is it correct to say "She is wriggling my kneepit with her foot"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

You're sitting with your knees bent, and your wife put her foot into your kneepit, then she twists and turn her foot in your kneepit as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**She is wriggling my kneepit with her foot**"?

Comment: Kneepit!  That's a new one.  I don't think it's a word but if you use it, it's bound to make a few people smile.  Are you sure it's not a legpit?

Comment: @EllieK Those unfetlocked by a classical education in physiology simply call this
the ***hock*** (think of *ham hocks*), also spelled *hough* and rhyming
with *knock* save in Scotland where it rhymes with Scottish *loch*.
Anatomically it’s the *popliteal fossa* because the muscle behind
the knee is the *popliteus*, a direct borrowing from Latin. Other such
*fossae* (pits) include the *axillary fossa* of the arm or shoulder,
the *antecubical fossa* of the elbow, and the *pyriform fossa* of the
small of the back infamously used for smuggling.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses a non-existent word ("kneepit").

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, please do some research first (they used kneepit), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Popliteal_fossa

Comment: Wikipedia and slang dictionaries (the only sources I could find) are not authoritative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have never heard the term kneepit before, if it is in common usage in your region, I do not see anything wrong with the above statement. In the US, this statement would be more commonly expressed as, “She is tickling the back of my knee with her toes.” Or, “She is wiggling her toes in the crook of my knee.”

Comment: I'm not entirely sure one can wriggle a kneepit, with or without the aid of a foot.  Technically only the foot would wriggle.  "She is wriggling her foot in my kneepit."

Comment: @EllieK - The word “kneepit” itself is troublesome to me. Maybe “Pit of my knee” would be better. Though, I still do not like that phrase. “Legpit” is even worse. It brings to mind an inappropriate slang. Now, “crook of my knee” is rather elegant. To *really* nitpick this subject, maybe we should denote that really only the toes are wriggling or (in the US) wiggling. Not the entire foot. That could possibly make the most acceptable answer that is close to the original, “She is wiggling her toes in the crook of my knee.” I think I will add that to my answer.

Comment: The key difference between *wiggle* and *wriggle* is that per the OED *wiggle* is ”to move to and fro or from side to side irregularly and lightly” while *wriggle* further involves a **twisting** motion. Transitive *wriggle* per the OED means “To cause to writhe, twist, or bend tortuously; to move or turn writhingly or with quick jerks.” You can wriggle your leg free of your trousers, and a snake can wriggle itself into a hole. For *wiggle* see also *wag, waggle, wiggle-waggle, waddle*; for *wriggle* see also *writhe, writhen, wring, wringle, wreathe, wreath, wrestle, wrench, wrist, wraith*.